# window phone 8 facebook connect

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to do the facebook connect sign in from this resource:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/windows-phone-connecting-with-facebook/

However,thats a different from the tutorial is that I'm using Window Phone 8 OS version instead of the window phone OS 7.1

Currently, Im stuck when clicked the post button, it should redirect me to the facebook login page but it give me an error page, "We're having trouble displaying this page,refesh the page or try again later"

Anyway to debug this and how to solve it? 
I'm still new in window phone development.

Answer (score 1):

I just read through the tutorial and I didn't see anything that wouldn't work for WP8 so I don't think that is the problem. You may want to take a look at the Facebook SDK for Windows & Windows Phone that we are working on. It is still alpha, but the samples and code contain everything you need to do auth on Windows Phone 8. https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winclient-sdk

Comment: ya, i do try the source from the github as you mentioned as well, but it still not working.. and I found out tat, my window phone 8 emulator have internet connection problem, which I cannot browse on the internet explorer in the emulator, I guess this is why it cannot connect to the facebook page as well. Any ideas?